# one more exercise on relations

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I would love to get someone check my task on relations again. In my seminar we talked about it very short time,but we need it for the exam. so it would be great if anyone could help me with both: content and form.

There is a amount of three elements $X =\{a,b,c\}$. Please give three relations to $X$ wit the following characteristics:

1. reflexive, not symmetrical, not transitive, $x\sim x+1, x \in X$, then
   $$
    a \sim a+1\\
    b \sim b+1 \\
    c \sim c+1 \\
   $$
2. symmetrical, not reflexive, not transitive, $x\sim x^2, x\in X$
   $$a\sim a^2$$
3. transitive, not reflexive, not symmetrical, $x-x'=x'', x \in  \mathbb R$
   $$a-b=c$$

Comment: I hope I translated your equations into latex correctly. Please check.

Comment: yes thank you!! is this true, are x +1. x² and x-x´ relations??

Comment: I'm not sure, I never had Math logic. Also, I don't believe I know what $x'$ means in the context of your problem.

Comment: Also, please keep in mind that the fact I corrected your post doesn't mean you don't have to do it by yourself in the future. Please, learn how to use $\LaTeX$ to type math equations here.

Comment: Okay thank you for editing!!

Comment: I just noticed that you haven’t accepted any answers. If you don’t know about accepting answers, you should probably read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: ah sorry. I didn´t know about this. Now i accepted the answer. thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X$ is just a set of three symbols, $a,b$, and $c$; they do not necessarily stand for numbers, so it does not make sense to talk about $a+1$, $a^2$, or $a-b$. For this problem you’re supposed to define the relations by listing the ordered pairs that belong to them.

1. Let $R$ be the relation. To make $R$ reflexive, you must make sure that $\langle a,a\rangle$, $\langle b,b\rangle$, and $\langle c,c\rangle$ are all in $R$. One way to make sure that $R$ is **not** symmetric is to put $\langle a,b\rangle$ in $R$ but not $\langle b,a\rangle$. Finally, if we put $\langle a,b\rangle$ and $\langle b,c\rangle$ in $R$ but not $\langle a,c\rangle$, then $R$ will not be transitive. At this point we have $$R=\{\langle a,a\rangle,\langle b,b\rangle,\langle c,c\rangle,\langle a,b\rangle,\langle b,c\rangle\}\;,$$ which is indeed reflexive but neither symmetric nor transitive. It fails to be symmetric because $a\sim_R b$, but $b\not\sim_R a$. It fails to be transitive because $a\sim_R b$ and $b\sim_R c$, but $a\not\sim_R c$.
2. There is a relation with just two ordered pairs that works here; can you find one?
3. There is a relation with just three ordered pairs that works here: can you find one? (There are relations with even fewer ordered pairs that also work, but for a slightly trickier reason; my hint is for a more obvious example.)

Comment: Thank you Brian Scott, you´re a good teacher! I try to find the other two now. will upload it very soon

Comment: @Sophia: I’ll be here.

Comment: so for symmetrical I could do R= {<a,b>, <b,a>, <b,c>, <c,b>} but not <a,c>, <c,a> because otherwise it woud be transitive. and no <a,a>, <b,b>, <c,c> so it´not reflexive?

Comment: and transitive: R:{<a,b>, <b,c>, <a,c>}?

Comment: @Sophia: Yes, that works for the symmetric one; you could even use just $R=\{\langle a,b\rangle,\langle b,a\rangle\}$. And the one that you have for the transitive relation is exactly the one that I had in mind.

Comment: for symmetrical, i will have t divide into two seperate relations maybe, like R= {<a,b>, <b,a>}, and R= { <b,c>, <c,b>}

Comment: @Sophia: You’re welcome! Good luck with your exam.

Comment: Thank you and have a good evening